# SQL Join w/ some Math thrown in

Tags: sql

Heck, maybe 'joining' isn't even involved.  I'm way out of my sql league here.  Could someone please help me out w/ the following:

Table A

```
 ItemId   ItemLookup   Price
 -------  ----------   -----
  1        123456       10.00
  2        234567        7.00
  3        345678        6.00
```

Table B

```
 ItemId   Location      Qty      QtyOnHold
 -------  ----------   -----     ---------
  1        1             26        20
  2        1             0         0
  3        1             12        6
  1        2             4         0
  2        2             2         1
  3        2             16        8
```

What I'm hoping to get is something that looks like

```
 ItemLookup, Price, (qty minus qtyonhold for loc1), (qty minus qtyonhold for loc2)
 or  123456, 10.00,         6,                              4
```

Thank you very much for any direction you can provide.

Comment: I wonder if you want more columns 1,2 and 3 ... so one

Comment: First try it without joining (ItemId instead of ItemLookup and Price). But you can't convert rows into columns using JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation and a `join`:

```
select a.ItemLookup,
       sum(case when Location = 1 then Qty - QtyOnHold end) as Location1,
       sum(case when Location = 2 then Qty - QtyOnHold end) as Location2
from tableb b join
     tablea a
     on b.ItemId = a.ItemId
group by a.ItemLookup;
```

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this

```
select  tablea.* ,
(select (qty- QtyOnHold) as qty from tableb where ItemId = tablea.ItemId ans Location = 1 ) as qtyl1,
(select (qty- QtyOnHold) as qty from tableb where ItemId = tablea.ItemId ans Location = 2) as qtyl2
 from tablea
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that there's only one row in `TableB` for each `ItemID + Location` combination. This is basically just a "pivot", you can learn various ways to do this in MySQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table).

```
SELECT ItemLookup, Price, 
    MAX(IF(Location = 1, Qty-QtyOnHold, 0)) avail1,
    MAX(IF(Location = 2, Qty-QtyOnHold, 0)) avail2
FROM TableA AS a
JOIN TableB AS b ON a.ItemId = b.ItemId
GROUP BY a.ItemId
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it may be possible to have a variable number of locations for each item. If this is the case, you need an aggregate function to convert/concatenate multiple rows into a column.
Here's an example with MySQL's group_concat function:

```
    select a.itemlookup,a.price,group_concat('loc ',location,'=',b.x order by location) as qty_minus_qtyonhold
    from tablea a,(select itemid,location,qty-qty_onhold x from tableb
    group by itemid,location) as b
    where a.itemid = b.itemid
    group by 1
```

You'll get a result like this:

```
 itemlookup   price  qty_minus_qtyonhold
 ----------   ------  ------------------
  123456      10.00   loc 1=6,loc 2=4
  234567      7.00    loc 1=0,loc 2=1
  345678      6.00    loc 1=6,loc 2=8
```

Not sure what DBMS you're using but there are similar alternatives for Oracle and SQL Server